# Eloquent: Complex Script

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Good day!

can be possible to change this script to **Eloquent Laravel**

```
SELECT concat(firstname, " ",lastname) as fullname,q_title,answer FROM `user_pivot_survey_answer` as upsa 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,q_title FROM survey_question) sq ON upsa.qid = sq.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM user_survey_answer) usa ON upsa.sid = usa.id
```

I translate it already to Eloquent, however, I don't know if is working

```php
 $testquery = DB::table('user_pivot_survey_answer')
     ->leftJoin(DB::select('SELECT id,q_title FROM survey_question'),function($join)) {
            $join->on('user_pivot_survey_answer.id', '=', 'survey_question.id'); 
      })
      ->leftJoin(DB::select('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM user_survey_answer'),function($join){
            $join->on('user_pivot_survey_answer.id', '=', 'user_survey_answer.id');
      });
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use sub select for joining ? Why not a direct join to survey_question and  user_survey_answer?

Comment: I just use select inside join because to make read the script fast, specially i want to select specific column.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```php
$testquery = DB::table('user_pivot_survey_answer as upsa')
     ->select(DB::raw('concat(firstname, " ", lastname) as fullname'), 'q_title', 'answer')
     ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT id,q_title FROM survey_question) sq'), 'upsa.qid', 'sq.id')
     ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM user_survey_answer) usa'), 'upsa.sid', 'usa.id');
```

Comment: is it okay to use DB::raw . to prevent sql injection?

Comment: It's ok to use`DB::raw()` *if* you don't inject unfiltered user input.